# Determining equality/inequality between 2 imaginary number

Tags: inequality

For example , there's 2 numbers which each of them can be a real number or an imaginary number and both of them can also be in the same number system (both real or both imaginary) , one of them is symbolized as A and the other as B , my question is , how do i determine their inequality or equality (bigger/smaller or equal) if one of them is imaginary number ? and if both of them is imaginary number with the same value (value A is the same as value B) , are they A=B ?

Comment: You cannot compare complex numbers - only the real ones. The equality of two complex numbers means that both real and imaginary parts of both numbers are equal. You can however compare the absolute values of two complex numbers,  since these are real quantities.

Comment: Various orderings can be defined on $\mathbb C$, for example, the dictionary order which compares the imaginary part after the real part. However, these orderings does not cooperate with the operations such as summation and multiplication, compare to what we have for real numbers.

Comment: If the two complex numbers are written as $z_1 = a_1+ib_1$ and $z_2=a_2+ib_2$ then $z_1=z_2$ iff $a_1=a_2$ and $b_1=b_2$ (provided $=$ is used in the usual sense of the term). You cannot usually claim that $z_1 > z_2$ or vice versa, only that $|z_1| > |z_2|$.